# Is $f(t)R(x;\sigma = 1)$ equivalent to $R(x; \sigma = f(t))$, where $R(x; \sigma)$ is a PDF with a single mode defined by $\sigma$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I have some function $f(t)$, which is known, and a PDF - for example the Rayleigh distribution:
$$R(x;\sigma) = \frac{x}{\sigma^2}e^{-x^{2}/(2 \sigma^2)}$$
and I use this function, $f(t)$, to define the mode (or shape parameter) of the Rayleigh distribution, such that
$$\sigma = f(t) \text{.}$$
This means that we can have a random variable, $F$ which is now drawn from
$$F(t) \sim \frac{x}{f(t)^2}e^{-x^{2}/(2 f(t)^2)}.$$

This must, "somehow", be connected, or equivalent, with the following
$$G(t) \sim f(t) R(x;\sigma = 1).$$
which could represent some noisy data which follows $f(t)$.

Are these expressions equivalent, or related, and if so how may I show this?

---

**Additional thoughts/rationale**

As I see it, assuming one fixes the seed of a random number generator, both $G(t)$ and $F(t)$ must produce the same random number, as:

- In the case of $F(t)$ the mode, $\sigma$ is now defined by the function $f(t)$, so the most likely number to be drawn from the distribution $F(t)$ should indeed be $f(t)$, for some value of $t$.
- In the case of $G(t)$ we have the function, f(t), scaled by a random number which is most likely to be $1$, as we have defined the mode of the Rayligh distribution to be $\sigma = 1$

Apart from this "logical" reasoning I can't find a way to prove/disprove this.

---

I have tried one additional train of thought, whereby if we consider
$$f(t)R(x;,\sigma = 1)$$
to be the "global" picture, and
$$R(x;,\sigma = f(t))$$
to be the local one. If we perform the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} R(x;\sigma) \ {\rm{d}}\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
which is the mean of a Rayleigh distribution when $\sigma = 1$ -- the mean being defined as
$$\mu =  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sigma $$
This may be spurious connection I am making out of desperation.

---

**Illustrative simulation**
This may be superfluous, but I thought an illustrative simulation may be helpful. It is written in Mathematica but it should be relatively easy to follow. Consider the function $f(t)$, I have defined it as a Lorentzian peak like function as an arbitrary function

```
f[w_, t0_, t_] := Abs[w^2 / (w^2 + (t - t0)^2)]
```

Then consider the two cases, as discussed above:

```
CaseOne = Table[RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[f[500, 5000, t]]],{t, 1, 10000}];
CaseTwo = Table[f[500, 5000, t] RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[1]],{t, 1, 10000}];
```

If we examine the histograms of `CaseOne` (red) and `CaseTwo` (blue) and both overlapped (purple), we can see the distributions are identical.

[image]

Comment: Also asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/476690/119261.

Comment: I misunderstood your intent, sorry!

Comment: $G(t)$ is not even guaranteed to be a p.d.f. (in $x$), so how exactly are random numbers generated out of $G(t)$?

Comment: @Saad are you saying that my notation should be instead, $G(x,t)$? Otherwise I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Q.P. When you say to generate random numbers from $F(t)$, I understand that $F(t)$ is used as a p.d.f with $t$ being a parameter. But this interpretation fails for $G(t)$ since $\int G(x;t)\,\mathrm dx=1$ doesn't necessarily hold. So how exactly to generate random numbers from $G(t)$?

Comment: @Saad No, I am saying $F(t)$ and $G(t)$ are the random numbers drawn from $R(x; \sigma = f(t))$ and $f(t)R(x; \sigma = 1)$ respectively. Perhaps my notation is incorrect but when I say $X\sim P(x)$ I mean the random number X is drawn from the distribution $P(x)$.

Comment: There are some issues with notation, but I think I understand what you are asking. Would this be an equivalent way of formulating your question? Suppose $X$ is a random variable following a Rayleigh $R(x, \sigma=1)$, then the random variable $cX$ follows a Rayleigh $R(x, \sigma=c)$ for any constant $c>0$?  More succinctly, for any $c > 0$:
$$X \sim R(x, \sigma=1) \quad \Rightarrow \quad cX \sim R(x, \sigma=c)$$

Comment: @SherwinLott You have the cases reversed, if I understand your notation it should rather be $cX \sim R(x, \sigma = 1)$ and   $X \sim R(x, \sigma = c)$.

Comment: I believe it's the other way? Suppose $c$ is small, e.g. $c=.01$.  Then $c X$ is going to be very close to zero, i.e. have a lower standard deviation.  (Once we clear that up though, is my way of phrasing it equivalent to your question?)

Comment: @SherwinLott I think the problem is notation, as you say. I'll write some code that illustrates my question. It will be in Mathematica but it's a fairly high level language so should be readable.

Comment: I don't think code is going to particularly help on math stack exchange (we can see already see what you posted on the stats exchange)--we need to get the mathematical notation down if we're going to prove it. As was pointed out by Saad, we multiply the random variable and not the pdf. Could you rephrase your question in terms of random variables?

Comment: @SherwinLott I can't think of a way to say it clearer than as I have written. I want to show that $X \sim cR(x, \sigma = 1)$ is the same as  $X \sim R(x, \sigma = c)$. Where $X$ is a random variable. If it helps we can proceed with your previous assumption in your first comment.

Comment: That's fine, I think we are close to making it clear. Question, what do you mean by $cR(x, \sigma=1)$?  Specifically $R(x, \sigma=1) = xe^{-x^{2}/2}$, so wouldn't $cR(x, \sigma=1) = cxe^{-x^{2}/2}$? This is clearly different from $R(x, \sigma=c) = \frac{x}{c^2}e^{-x^{2}/(2 c^2)}$.  Do you see the notational issue with writing it this way? Instead, I believe the question you want to ask is what I wrote earlier with random variables.  Which is that, if we scale up the random numbers you are trying to generate by a constant $c$, then the standard deviation of their pdfs scale up proportionally.

Comment: Yes, I think I now get it. Yes you are right in terms of the random variables is better!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable with the standard Rayleigh pdf:
$$R(x;\sigma=1) = xe^{-x^{2}/2}$$
In other words, $X$ is one of the data points you are randomly generating. If we multiply the data point by some constant $c>0$ we get a data point $Y = cX$. You are asking whether the pdf of $Y$ is:
$$R(y;\sigma=c) = \frac{y}{c^2}e^{-y^{2}/(2c^2)}$$

---

Proof: Denote the probability that $X$ is less than or equal to some real number $x$ by:
$$P(X \leq x)$$
Then, the probability $Y$ is less than or equal to some real number $y$ is:
$$\begin{align}
P(Y \leq y) &= P(cX \leq y) \\
&= P(X \leq y/c)
\end{align}$$
Now, the pdf of $Y$ is defined as the derivative of $P(Y \leq y)$ with respect to $y$:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dy}P(Y \leq y) &= \frac{d}{dy} P(X \leq y/c) \\
&= \frac{d}{dy} \int_{0}^{y/c} R(x, \sigma = 1) dx
\end{align}$$
By [Leibniz's integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):
$$= c^{-1}R(y/c, \sigma=1)$$
Plugging $x=y/c$ into the pdf $R(x, \sigma = 1) = xe^{-x^{2}/2}$ gives:
$$\begin{align}
&= c^{-1} \left( \frac{y}{c}e^{-(y/c)^{2}/2} \right) \\
&= \frac{y}{c^2}e^{-y^{2}/(2c^2)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Appreciate it!! I also added my "simulation" just to really labour the point -- but looking at your answer I think it isn't necessary. Let me digest it and I'll award the bounty!

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you have any questions about the writeup/notation.

Comment: Thanks again for this answer, it's a problem that's been bugging me a for a while and this helps make a problem I've been working on internally consistent -- thanks!